# Nested link_to_function/insert_html does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype, nested, rjs, partial-classes

Here is a simple example of the problem.

http://gist.github.com/235729

In short, if you have a index.rhtml with:

```
<%= link_to_function "A link to insert a partial with nested insert_html" do |page|
      page.insert_html :top, :with_a_nested_insert_html, :partial => 'example_partial_with_nested_insert_html'
    end %>
```

And a _example_partial_with_nested_insert_html.rhtml

```
<%= link_to_function "A nested link to insert_html" do |page|
      page.insert_html :top, :with_a_nested_insert_html, :partial => 'you_wont_see_this'
    end %>
```

It breaks the "A link to insert a partial with nested insert_html". I am thinking something needs to be done to protect the javascript in the partial.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

```
<%= link_to_function( "insert it", :id => 'foo') do |page| 
            partial = escape_javascript(render :partial => "my_partial", :object => Object.new)
            page <<  "$('#my_div').append(\"#{partial}\")"
        end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but I strongly think the syntax should be more something like :

```
<% link_to_function "A link to insert a partial with nested insert_html" do |page|
   <%= page.insert_html :top, :with_a_nested_insert_html, :partial => 'example_partial_with_nested_insert_html' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using escape_javascript before rendering the partials - [see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escapejavascript-before-rendering-a-partial).