# rails escape_javascript in .net

Tags: c#, .net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-2

For rails developer please check my last paragraph.

Is there an equivalent of escape_javascript in rails for .net specifically .net mvc2?
I am going to return some JavaScript which needs to be escaped since I am getting the code from another view using RenderPartialViewToString http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

You can see what escape_javascript does here [Why escape_javascript before rendering a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial/1623813#1623813) if your not familiar with its functionality.

Rails developers:
It feels like this function should be easy to implement or port for rails so can someone explain what it does more than just escaping qoutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go [here,](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html) and click on the show source link, you can see the source to the method.  It is just a Regex.Replace() call.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC provides [9 ActionResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx), one of them is the [JavascriptResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult.aspx).

In your Action method:

> return JavaScript("javascript code");

Comment: But I want to write my javascript code in a view and I also want to be able to use partials for the javascript code which needs to be escaped. Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery to see what I want to do if you are interested in a nicer solution than returning javascript from your action.

Comment: Now I understand. You have the same problem as I have, but I haven't found a solution yet. Since MVC can be extended you could try creating your own ActionResult.