# Rendering partial inside js.erb. Is it possible to get raw string so I can strip whitespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, haml, renderpartial

I want to render a partial in my js.erb file so I can use the generated HTML in my Javascript. Here's some code to serve as an example.

**create.js.erb**

```
$(function(){
  var html = "<%= render(:partial => `pretty_box`) %>";
  $("#container").prepend(html);
});
```

**_pretty_box.html.haml**

```
.pretty_box_container
  .title
    Something Pretty
```

When create.js.erb is rendered, I get the following:

```
$(function(){
  var html = "<div class="pretty_box_container>
    <div class="title">
      Something Pretty
    </div>
</div>";
  $("#container").prepend(html);
});
```

As you would expect, this breaks my javascript. I need to strip the whitespace from the result of rendering the partial. The problem is the return value of `render` is an [`ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html) object, which overrides all "unsafe" methods (see [**UNSAFE_STRING_METHODS**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html)), including `strip`. So calling `render(:partial =>`pretty_box`).strip` HTML-encodes the entire string.

I've tried all sorts of combinations using the methods `html_safe` or `to_s`. They don't work because they return `self`, and using `raw` doesn't work either because it calls `to_s.html.safe`.

I know I can append `>` and `<` characters to my HAML, but I don't want to do that for every line of every partial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not whitespaces, but quotes.

```
$(function(){
  var html = "<div class="pretty_box_container>
                         ^
                         This is where you go wrong
```

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  var html = "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'pretty_box')) %>";
  $("#container").prepend(html);
});
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial/1623813#1623813) on StackOverflow for an explanation about `escape_javascript`.