# Rails 3 AJAX page redirecting after uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using AJAX to upload an image (with carrierwave gem) and want to display the image after uploading without refreshing or redirecting the page. Currently, after I upload an image it redirects to /images rather than staying on the / home page.

image_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @image = Image.new(params[:image])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @image.save
     format.js
    end
  end
end
```

_upload.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @image, :html => { :multipart => true }, :remote => true do |f|%>
  <p>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload image", :class => 'btn primary', :id => 'image-upload' %></p>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('images-show').replaceWith('<%=j render 'shared/show_image' %>');
```

How do I prevent the redirect to /images after an image upload?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but a little friendly advice. Always use escape_javascript when rendering a partial to avoid malicious code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial for more info. So it should be `$('images-show').html('<%=escape_javascript(render 'shared/show_image') %>');`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Didn't know exactly what escape_javascript does. I read in the API docs that j can be used in place of escape_javascipt, is this true?

Comment: it is doing a POST request. How do I tell it to do a GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, make sure you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile. Then make sure that you have `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in the head of your html document `application.html.erb` and that the file you are including, `application.js` has the lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```