# Rails options_for_select in js.erb not being rendered

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a js.erb with this basic content:

```
$("#currencies").html("<%= options_for_select([['Dollar', '$']])%>");
```

And the html is not being added to the element #currencies.

However if I do it like this:

```
$("#currencies").html('<option value="$">Dollar</option>');
```

The html is being updated.

What can be happening?

For debugging purposes I have tried this:

```
alert("<%= options_for_select([['Dollar', '$']]) %>");
```

And it doesn't show anything either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape javascript with <%=j .. %>

```
<%=j options_for_select .. %>
```

or

```
<%= escape_javascript(..) %>
```

or

```
$('some_element').replaceWith('<%=j render 'some/element_template' %>');
```

from [api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)

Comment: some explanation in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial)