# How do you create javascript functions that are available project-wide in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I put the following function in my application.js:

```
function test() {
  alert("See Me")
}
```

classrooms/_new_small.html.haml:

```
:javascript
  alert('test');
  test();
```

In my application.html.haml I'm using the following:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

I'm getting a `test is not defined` error in my firebug console.  Isn't the test function supposed to be available project-wide because its in the application.js file? Thanks

edit:  I'm rendering the page via javascript.  Would that affect it?

```
$('#test_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'classrooms/new_small') %>");
```

Comment: yes it should be, can you post your partial?

Comment: Just updated it with the partial code that is calling the function.

Comment: Are you sure your controller is rendering a layout that includes `application.js` ?

Comment: Why the partial and not just the javascript in your response?

Comment: Is your `javascript_include_tag` in your `<head>`, or is it at the end of your `<body>`?  If it appears at the end of your `<body>`, (i.e.: *after* you try to call it from your view), then it won't have been defined yet.  Try replacing your call to `test()` with `$(function () { test() });` to see if it succeeds.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you are using asset pipeline & coffeescript: **Don't write code in application.js**

In order to keep clean structure, create a folder (eg: `application`) in `app/assets/javascripts`

then require it in your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require_tree ./application
```

Create a coffee file (eg: `app/assets/javascripts/application/my_feature.js.coffee`

```
@test = ->
  alert('Hello world')
```

Coffee output:

```
(function() {

  this.test = function() {
    return alert('Hello world');
  };

}).call(this);
```

It's preferable to use namespaces:

```
@myGreatFeature =
  test: ->
    alert('Hello world')
```

or according to the coffeescript FAQ, you could write

```
namespace = (target, name, block) ->
  [target, name, block] = [(if typeof exports isnt 'undefined' then exports else window), arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
  top    = target
  target = target[item] or= {} for item in name.split '.'
  block target, top

namespace 'myGreatFeature', (exports) ->
  exports.test = ->
    alert('Hello world')
```

then you can call `myGreatFeature.test()` everywhere

Comment: How is Coffeescript directly relevant?

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard Perhaps it is not directly relevant, but it seems at least indirectly relevant as "Rails ships with CoffeeScript by default" per https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, remove `escape_javascript`, but it's **dangerous** see [Why escape_javascript before rendering a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial) . 
Currently you want to execute

```
$('#test_container').html("<script>
//<![CDATA[
 alert('test');
 test();
//]]>
</script>
```

which is converted into

```
$('#test_container').html("<script>\n  //<![CDATA[\n    alert(\'test\');\n    test();\n  //]]>\n<\/script>\n");
```

### How do i solve this problem ?

i will include project_wide.js in app/assets/javascripts/ and then tell `application.js` to include my file .

```
//= require project_wide
```

Be sure to put the above line after

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Now, whatever i put in `app/assets/javascripts/project_wide.js` it will shamelessly appear in whole project **except the files which are in `public/` folder** . In this file, i will put everything which i want to execute .

#### Follow common practice

Currently,you are adding javascript directly inside  `classrooms/_new_small.html.haml` which is uncommon. Mostly , rails developer put such things in `assets/javascripts/*.js` or call `content_for :javascript_custom` block in views , which is added in layout file by `yield :javascript_custom`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this without an issue.  Here's how I did it.

// application.js

```
var test=function(){
  alert("hello");
}
```

// in a view, whichever one, i have a content_for :additional_javascripts

```
<% content_for :additional_javascripts do %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    test();
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

// in application layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= yeild(:additional_javascripts) %>
```

Furthermore, if I want to alert this dynamically later on I could append it to the page and call it then, or put it in a click listener or something.

I like the syntax var functionName = function(){...} because it properly scopes the method.  Also, because of the way javascripts are compiled through the asset pipeline, adding the ; at the end of every executed line is very important.

This also worked for me as far as loading the script dynamically and calling it from anywhere in the page:

```
$("#click_me").live("click", function(){
  $("<script />").text("test();").appendTo("body");
});
```

And in the page I had a simple link.

```
<a href="#" id="click_me">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of the line

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

rather than

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all'
```

If the former is missing, your javascript won't be included.

Comment: Thanks - I mis-copied.  I was using the javascript_include_tag

Comment: If you View Source on the page, is a script tag being generated? If so, is your test function in the URL the script tag points to?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

in your `application.html.erb` file

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your function `test()` is indented, which suggests it is nested. If you define a function in the scope of another function, it will not be available outside of it.

For example this should work, using jQuery:

```
function test() { /* do something */ }

// another file or inline script

$(function() {
   test();
});
```

But this won't

```
(function() {
   function test() {}
})();

// another file

test(); // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for looking but its not indented in the actual code.  Cutting and pasting in into stackoverflow caused the indent.

Answer (score 0):

put all those javascript functions in *application.js* file and 
include `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in *head tag* of your layout file