# render (partial) and scope between elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a checkout popup I would like to share between different pages (event, video meeting ...), so I thunk creating a shaded element /views/shared/_checkout.html.erb, and insert <%= render "shared/checkout" %> in my pages.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: popup_payment is not defined

All the html and javascript is this shared page.
I just can't understand why from my pages (event, video ...) I **can not** call the javascript from this shared component.

the html and the javascript is present when I check the source. I was excepting that render / render partial was acting some code injection, am I wrong ?

How could I preserve the DRY - **Don't repeat Yourself** - in ERB ?
And have the elements / javascript communicate betweek page and included javascript ?

Here is some pseudo code example :
pageA.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag('pinandchip.png', size: '18x18'), '#', onclick: 'popup_payment();', class: "btn flat" %>
```

...

view/shared/_popup.html.erb

```
<script>
function popup_payment() {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the class `payment-popup-button` to your button and create a new file in app/assets/javascripts/shared called `popup.js`.

In that file you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('payment-popup-button').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#popup_payment_div').show();
  });
});
```

This assumes that you're using `jQuery`, and that you've already rendered the popup code somewhere on the page, but it's hidden.

If you need to render a fresh form every time or populate the form with dynamic data you'll probably have to create controller actions that `respond_to` and `render` `js.erb` to get you the right markup.

It's hard to say exactly without seeing more code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I found anotheur solution with komponent

Answer (score 0):

Are you ensure that your javascript function is loaded in all pages?

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096301/how-do-you-create-javascript-functions-that-are-available-project-wide-in-ruby-o) answer how to have global javascript functions on rails projects.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution with this gem :

https://github.com/komposable/komponent

it fulfill my needs : create external components