# Rails render JS partial printing code to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using AJAX in my Rails app to render a JS error message when needed. It was working initially, but now coming back to it some time later, it still shows the JS error message but for some reason it now also **prints the entire JS file as HTML in the window**. This is what's called in the controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :partial => 'error' }
end
```

My file named `_error.js.erb` contains some JS which isn't relevant as regardless of what it contains Rails prints it to the window still.

**This is what the JS looks like outputted to the window: (I tried commenting out the JS to see if it made a difference)**

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Did you solve it finally?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with some modification :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Inside the action and in the view action_name.js.erb write your js code ar if you want to put your erb then use escape_javascript.

Check the following link :

[Why escape_javascript before rendering a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial)

Comment: I tried what you said, and when using `escape_javascript` nothing at all is rendered. If I just use `render` then the same problem as I described above happens. Any idea why it might not render at all when escaping?

Comment: just put a blank alert in the js.erb file and check first id it is coming or not.

Comment: When using `escape_javascript` it is not. Without, it works, and then also prints to page.

Comment: not clear about the problem. please check the if there is any syntax error present in your code or not.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! In case there will be someone else wondering a few years later, there's the answer: you should put rendered value in a `javascript_tag` inside your html.erb. Like this:

```
javascript_tag render: 'error'
```

that will put what rendered between `<script>...</script>` tags and escape all unnecessary code.

[Here's](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag) the documentation on it