# Rails 4: bootstrap 3 modal.(hide) do nothing inside render

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

In my **action.js.erb** i'v got

```
<%= render 'smthng' %>
```

In **_smthng.js.erb**

```
...    
$("#modal").modal("hide")
...
```

and then i call action, modal window don't hide, but if i put *$("#modal").modal("hide")* inside **action.js.erb** without render, modal window hide correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to be escaping javascript.  See the second answer here for more: [Why escape_javascript before rendering a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial)

Comment: But i don't need to render html partion, i just want to call mhetod