# invoke js from controller - simple search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a search form in a `modal` as below:

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :remote => true, :method => :get do %> 
  <input type="text" name="search_name">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
<% end %>

<div id="channels"></div>
```

the above form invoke below method in my controller:

```
#my_controller.rb:

def search
  parsed_json = JSON.parse(@json_string) # fetch some json data
  render do |index|
    ndex.html {}
    index.js {}
  end
end
```

so I expect the above search method to render below `index.js.erb` from `app/view/my_controller` to update my `div` :

```
$("#channels").html("<%= render :partial => "channels" %>")
```

after clicking the search button the view can not be updated because `index.js.erb` can not be invoked, any idea?

P.S: I am using `rails 3.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 'escape_javascript' tag in your index.js.erb

Replace:

```
$("#channels").html("<%= render :partial => "channels" %>")
```

With:

```
$("#channels").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "channels" %>")
```

Read more on this using: [Why escape_javascript before rendering a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial)

Also, I may be wrong but this seems a bit odd:

```
render do |index|
  index.html {}
  index.js {}
end
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}
  format.js { render 'index.js.erb' }
  #                  ^ If you dont write this, it will look for search.js.erb in your views dir
end
```