# the purpose of "escape_javascript" in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am kind new to rails dev,  I saw some guys used `escape_javascript` when rendering html,  but I don't know what exactly the purpose of using it.When should I use it? could anyone provide some detailed example for this?  much appreciated

Comment: Please search for this, there are definitive answers out there. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial

Answer (score 0):

You don't want users posting JavaScript that the browser actually executes?