# Rails partial error missing template even though there is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason the show link throws error while trying to render its partial, even though the partial exists (named _show.html.erb)

Made no changes to the routes file. It simply has the root declaration and `resources :notes`

And I have not deleted the original "show.html.erb" generated by Scaffold.(matters?)

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <% note.title %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', note, remote: true, class: "note-show" %> 
<% end %>

<div id="note-show">

</div>
```

**_show.html.erb**

```
<% note.title %>
<% note.body %>
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('#note-show').html("<%= render :partial => 'show' %>");
```

**notes controller**

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def index
    @notes = Note.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def show
    respond_to do |format|               
      format.js
      format.html
    end  
end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_note
      @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**Error is**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Notes#show

Showing /home/arjun/rails/notes/app/views/notes/show.html.erb where line # raised:
Missing partial notes/_show, application/_show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/arjun/rails/notes/app/views"
  * "/home/arjun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p431/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"
```

Strangely on some links it simply shows

```
$('#note-show').html("hello
");
```

I found this by using the Browser Page Source

What is incorrect here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial

Answer (score 0):

In show.js.erb you have to escape javascript, (escape_javascript or j)

```
$('#note-show').html("<%= j render 'show' %>");
```