# Render three different partials depending on button clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a layout like this:

home/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="optionscontainer btn-group btn-group-justified">
   <%= link_to posts_path, class:"options btn btn-primary", remote: true do %>
      <i class="fa fa-book optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>All posts
   <% end %>
   <%= link_to stories_path, class:"options btn btn-primary", remote: true do %>
      <i class="fa fa-book optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>All stories
   <% end %>
</div>
   <div id="content" class="">
   </div>
```

In posts_controller.rb

I have:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #looks for views/books/index.html.erb
      format.js   #looks for views/books/index.js.erb
    end
  end
```

In stories_controller.rb

I have:

```
def index
    @stories = Story.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #looks for views/books/index.html.erb
      format.js   #looks for views/books/index.js.erb
    end
  end
```

In my views/posts/index.js.erb

```
$("#content").html("<%= j (render 'posts') %>");
```

In my views/stories/index.js.erb

```
$("#content").html("<%= j (render 'stories') %>");
```

And I also have `_posts.html.erb` in `views/posts` and `_stories_html.erb` in `views/stories`

What happens is when i click on the posts button i renders the view but when i click on the stories button nothing renders?

Comment: How do you wanna render them? As an AJAX request? Do you know how to create an action on a controller?

Comment: I'm new to rails, and web development, If AJAX is the best way please do show an example

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, before getting into the solution, lets understand the `request-response` cycle.

When you search for http://stackoverflow.com, what happens is you're sending a request from the `client`(your browser) to the StackOverflow(SO) `server`. The client and server communicate through `HTTP` protocol and if the user's requesting for something that the server knows, it serves(sends) the response(html, css, js files). The browser knows how to display the html content received from the server. Every browser has its own stylesheet(`user-agent-stylesheet`) and it also applies the styles in the css files linked in the html page sent back from the server. Note that this all happens **synchronously** and while the `server` is processing the client's request, the browser tab is `inactive` as its waiting for the server's response. The same process happens when you click on a link. It creates a new request to the server.

The response from the server can be `HTML`, `JSON`, `XML` etc. As you might have noticed, the `synchronous` communication is not something we always want.

If we make a new `synchronous` request, the browser fetches `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` and `image` files all over again(lets not get into caching). And we don't want to update the whole page for every request.

Often, only parts of the page are updated after a request and it provides a good user experience.

This is where Javascript is good at. It has the power to make requests to the server asynchronously(the web page doesn't reload) and also update parts of the page using something called `AJAX`([Asynchronous Javascript XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)).

A typical AJAX request goes like this. You make a request to the server  but this time asynchronously and the server responds with `XML` rather than `HTML` and `Javascript` parses the `XML` document updates the part of the page. Eventhough its called AJAX, now-a-days, JSON is used for exchanging information across services.

So, to make a AJAX request, we need a link which when clicked sends a `XMLHttpRequest`(asynchronous request) and the server should respond with `JSON` or `XML` or and then the script should parse the response and update the `DOM`([Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)). Making an AJAX request in `Vanilla JS`(plain javascript) is complex and people normally use `Jquery`'s `ajax` method to issue an AJAX request(less lines of code). See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more information.

But in `rails`, its even easier. We can make an AJAX request using `UJS`([Unobtrusive Javascript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript)). Lets see it in action.

To make a link send an AJAX request, you need to set `remote: true`in the `link_to` helper. This adds a `data-remote=true`in the generated HTML.

For example the following erb

```
<%= link_to "All books", books_path, remote: true %>
```

generates the html

```
<a data-remote="true" href="/books">All books</a>
```

Ok. Now we're all set to make an `AJAX` request. Modify your code as

```
<div style="margin-top:50px;" class="wrapper">
  <div class="optionscontainer btn-group btn-group-justified">

    <%= link_to posts_path, class:"options btn btn-primary", remote: true do %>
      <i class="fa fa-book optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>All posts
    <% end %>


   <%= link_to stories_path, class:"options btn btn-primary", remote: true do %>
      <i class="fa fa-rss optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>All stories
    <% end %>

   <%= link_to books_path, class:"options btn btn-primary", remote: true do %>
      <i class="fa fa-users optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>All books
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <!-- The content goes here -->
</div>
```

I assume you have the controllers, models and views setup. Also Execute `rake routes` in the terminal to see the existing routes of your application. You should see the following(Order isn't important)

```
Prefix  Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
posts   GET    /posts(.:format)            posts#index
stories GET    /stories(.:format)          stories#index
books   GET    /books(.:format)            books#index
```

Note: `format` here corresponds to the returned format which can be `html`, `js`, `xml` or `json`.

`posts_path` in one of the `url_helper` which points to `posts#index`, meaning whenever a request is made to the server in a `rails` application, it first reaches the router and is dispatched to the corresponding `controller` action specified in `routes.rb`

In this case, if we make a request to `http://localhost:3000/books`, the request is sent to the books#index action. In the action, you can fetch the data from the `database` and send the response to the client.

Since we are interested in AJAX and we have specified `remote:true`, rails will expect a `JS` response to be returned to the client(ie. a `script` which is responsible for rendering content dynamically).

I will explain how to deal with the AJAX request for `BooksController` and you can apply the same idea for other controllers.(`posts` and `stories`).

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @books = Book.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #looks for views/books/index.html.erb
      format.js   #looks for views/books/index.js.erb
    end

  end

  #other actions
end
```

All we're doing here is telling the controller to render `index.js.erb` if the client requests for a JS response or to render `index.html.erb` in case of HTML response. How does rails knows to render `index.html.erb` or `index.js.erb` when we didn't specify the file to render? Thats what rails is popular for.Rails follows [Convention Over Configuration](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Getting_Started/Convention_Over_Configuration).

Actually, the `controller` infers the template to render from the `action` name.

The next step is to make use of `@books` to update the `#content` div. Before adding the code to render all the books, we need a template to render right? Thats where partials come in. A partial is a reusable `view' and  a partial in rails is prefixed with '_'. For example:`_books.html.erb`is a partial for`books`.

Create a partial `app/views/books/_books.html.erb`

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="book">
    #Display the fields
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now create `app/views/books/index.js.erb` and add the following:

```
$("#content").html("<%= j (render 'books') %>");
```

This one-liner will render the partial `_books.html.erb` into the `#content` div. Wait. How does it work? Lets break it into pieces.

Anything inside `<%=  %>` is ruby code. Its executed and the value is replaced in place of `<%= %>`. The `erb` templating engline allows you to write `ruby` code inside `javascript`. So, what does this do?

```
<%= j (render 'books') %>
```

It will render the `books/_books.html.erb`, inferred from the parameter to `render`. It returns the html generated by `_books.html.erb`.

What does `j` do? Its actually an alias of `escape_javascript` method. It is used to escape the content returned from the partial `_books.html.erb`.

Explaining the reason for `escaping` html will make this answer even longer. I strongly recommend you to read kikito's answer(the 3rd one) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial) SO thread.

So, we are passing html from the partial as a string(note the quotes around `<%= %>`) to `html` method which is added inside the `#content` div. Thats it!

I recommend you to inspect the server logs and explore the `Network` tab in Developer tools to get a deep understanding of how AJAX works.

Do the same for the other controllers(`PostsController` and `StoriesController`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: When Im running into a small problem, I have the views for book, posts etc, but these buttons are on an index#home page and use a different controller called index and method home. I have updated my question.

Comment: @GurmukhSingh I don't understand you. There are three links in the index#home view where each of them send a request to different controllers. In my answer, you can find the links point to `stories_path`, `books_path` and `posts_path`. In my answer, I have written the steps to be done for `books_controller` so that the link for `books_path` renders a `js` response. You can repeat the same steps(data is different for each) for other controllers. If thats not what you want, please comment on the desired behaviour.

Comment: so basically im trying to render the views in a separate view. Post and Books and separate scaffoldsso they have their own views. Im working in another controller called index, so im applying the logic above to the index controller, where I create the .js file for the index app/views/index/home.js.erb and then place $("#content").html("<%= j (render 'books') %>"); in it and then for the posts i do the same $("#content").html("<%= j (render 'posts') %>"); which goes in the same home.js.erb. I hope this makes scenes :? This then doesn't work?

Comment: @GurmukhSingh Why do you want to have all the scripts in `index/home.js.erb`? If you really want to do it that way, then there's a problem with it. In the links, you need to pass additional information as to which button was clicked and not just that, you need conditionals in your `index.js.erb` to render a specific partial which makes it too complicated. With my solution, you're directing the request to a different controller which avoids conditionals and thus less code. Makes sense?

Comment: I edited my question showing how i have implemented you solution, but its not working perfectly

Comment: @GurmukhSingh, Are you saying that it works for `posts` but not for `stories`? Have you modified your `StoriesController#index` to render `js` response? If thats fine, after clicking the stories button, please inspect the `network` tab in your dev tools and see the server logs to see what's happening. Post the log and let me try to solve the issue.

Comment: yh it works for posts but not stories, what am i looking for in network tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121206/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-gurmukh-singh).

Comment: @AunKumar it works fine, it was a small error on my side! Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

The links would have to be set to `remote: true` and they would have to point to different actions (or to the same but receiving different parameters).

And those actions would have to respond to js and render its js view.

It would be something like this:

Your view:

```
<div style="margin-top:50px;" class="wrapper">
  <div class="optionscontainer btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <%= link_to 'All Posts', posts_path, class: 'options btn btn-primary', method: :get, remote: true %>
  </div>
  <div id='placeholder'>
    <%= render 'all_posts' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

views/posts/index.js.erb

```
$('#placeholder').html("<%= j (render 'all_posts') %>");
```

Answer (score -2):

As you want to achieve this from single method index#home. Then you have to pass some extra info with the link as

```
<div style="margin-top:50px;" class="wrapper">
  <div class="optionscontainer btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a style="background-color:#4183D7;" href="<%= path_to_index_home(request: :p) %>" class="options btn btn-primary" data-remote=true><i class="fa fa-book optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>All posts</a>
    <a style="background-color:#59ABE3;" href="<%= path_to_index_home(request: :s) %>" class="options btn btn-primary" data-remote=true><i class="fa fa-rss optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>all stories</a>
    <a style="background-color:#81CFE0;" href="<%= path_to_index_home(request: :b) %>" class="options btn btn-primary" data-remote=true><i class="fa fa-users optionseach" aria-hidden="true"></i>all books</a>
  </div>
  <div data-load-partial>
    <%= render 'name_of_your_default_partial' , locals: {collection: @collection} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now we have to edit our controller. Add this line at top of your controller

```
ALLOWED_REQUESTS = { p: 'Post' , s: 'Story' , b: 'Book' }
```

Edit your home action as

```
@request = params[:request].blank? ? 'Post' : ALLOWED_REQUEST[params[:request].to_sym]
@collection = @request.constantize.all
```

Now its time to render appropriate partial. If you have different table structure and you want to display different fields with different html then you can create three different partials as _book.html.erb , _story.html.erb , _post.html.erb and you can call it as in your home.js.erb file

```
$('[data-load-partial]').html('<%= j render partial: "#{@request.downcase}" , locals: { collection: @collection } %>');
```

If you want to use the same partial for the three types then you can do it as

```
$('[data-load-partial]').html('<%= j render partial: "name_of_your_partial" , locals: { collection: @collection } %>');
```