# Create a Modal to Add new user from Navbar in bootstrap 3 modal - Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I am having an issue creating a user in a modal from my navbar. I want to add the link to allow an administrator to create a new user from a link as opposed to going to users index and use the modal button there.

> **My nav-bar link:**

```
 <li><%= link_to "Add User", new_user_path, remote: true %></li>
```

> **My Modal so far:**

```
found in: _create.html.erb

<%= content_tag :div, class: "modal fade", id: "createUser" do %>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               FORM HERE
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit "Create New User", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **my create.js.erb**

```
$('#createUser').modal('hide');

$(".email").val('');
$(".password").val('');
$(".f_name").val('');
$(".l_name").val('');
$(".primary_tel").val('');

$('#table_body').prepend('<%= j render partial: 'user_row', locals: {user: @user} %>');
$('#user_row_<%= @user.id %>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

> **users controller / new action**

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

User form I want to turn into a modal:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_ident %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_ident %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :f_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :f_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :l_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :l_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :primary_tel %>
    <%= f.text_field :primary_tel %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role_id %>
    <%= collection_select(:user, :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you explain what error you're getting?

Comment: @ArunKumar There is no error at all, it just wont load or display the modal.. pretty much like a dead link.

Comment: Can you post the code in `new` action of `UsersController` and in `new.js.erb`?

Comment: I have the  _create.js.erb ill try renaming it to new and add a format block to new aswell

Comment: Post the code of the view you're rendering for the `new` action

Comment: its actually the create action i want to use for this, however there is no user_create path ?

Comment: i essentially want to put my user create form in a modal i can access from the nav bar

Comment: @ArunKumar, im not sure what else you need here? my goal is to turn the user create form into a modal that the admin can access from the navbar at any time. My original thought process was to put it under the new action but thinking about it now it makes no sense to me.. it should stay under the create action

Comment: I am adding my answer. In the meanwhile, to understand the workflow of AJAX in rails, please read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875347/render-three-different-partials-depending-on-button-clicked/38939134#38939134) P.S. I am not advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to display the modal in the `index` view of `UsersController`. Add your code in `_create.html.erb` to the top of `users/index.html.erb`. Your modal won't display unless you explicitly ask it to. Since you're rendering a form in the modal for `@user`, you need to define what `@user` is in `index` action.

```
# users_controller.rb

def index
  @users = User.all
  @user = User.new
```

end

You have specified `remote:true` in your link to `new_user_path`, you have to render a `js` response in the `new` action.

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js #Looks for `users/new.js.erb`
    #other formats
  end
end
```

Since we already have the modal template in `index.html.erb`, all you need to do in `new.js.erb` is to display the modal.

```
# new.js.erb

$("#createUser").modal('show');
```

Since you have `create.js.erb` ready, thats all to be done.

**EDIT**: If you want to place this link in the navigation bar, you should add the modal template to a partial(say `layouts/_new_user_modal.html.erb`) and render it in `application.html.erb` which is common to all the views. Also, you need to make a change to your form. Instead of

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

use

```
<%= form_for(User.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

This way you don't have to define `@user` in every action of your application ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, so I actually want to display the modal anywhere in the application. its working in the users/index page now, however i would like to be able to just go and hit the link and pop the modal anywhere i am in the app.. is this doable?

Comment: @ShawnWilson, Updated my answer. Does this help?

Comment: this is Fantastic! thanks much! And so you know im going through the article you wrote! Fantastic read and ill def keep on learning my AJAX and JS!

Comment: @ShawnWilson Thats a long read. Thanks for reading. Glad that it helped.