# rails 5.1: pass variable to partial through ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to rails and experimenting. After I managed to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941608/show-partial-in-the-same-page-using-ajax-request), I was now trying to do the following:

when clicking on a link for a setting's name, it's description should be rendered in a partial on the same page. I managed to render the partial, but only if I put some static text in it. For some reason I'm not able to pass the @fbs variable and thus to select the descriptions. I tried many different suggestions on other similar questions but I really don't get how I should do it. I'm using ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5.1

Here is my _settingsfb.html.erb (which is a partial of index.html.erb and which contains the Link_to)

```
<div class="container fluid">
  <div class="row">


    <!-- settings links -->
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Settings</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <% @fbs.each do |fbs| %>
<ul>
      <li>  <%= link_to fbs.name, controller: 'settingsfb', action: 'show', id: fbs.id,remote: true %></li>
        </ul><% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- setting description -->

  <div class="col-md-4">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Description</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="desc">
      <!-- here goes the description partial -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

here the settingsfb_controller (the relevant part)

```
class SettingsfbController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_setting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /settings
  # GET /settings.json
  def index
    @settings = Setting.all
    @fbs = Setting.where("Sns = 1")
  end



  # GET /settings/1
  # GET /settings/1.json
  def show
       respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end
```

the show.js.erb

```
$("#desc").html("<%= j render 'settingsfb/show' %>");
```

and the _show partial

```
<%= @fbs.name %>
```

this is what I get when I click on a the link

```
 Started GET "/settingsfb/show?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-14 17:08:34 +0200
    Processing by SettingsfbController#show as JS
      Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
      Setting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Rendering settingsfb/show.js.erb
      Rendered settingsfb/_show.html.erb (2.6ms)
      Rendered settingsfb/show.js.erb (3.8ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
        1: <%= @fbs.name %>

    app/views/settingsfb/_show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_settingsfb__show_html_erb___617047289144576595_70310163068960'
    app/views/settingsfb/show.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_settingsfb_show_js_erb___3755597588635490219_70310163079560'
    app/controllers/settingsfb_controller.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in show'
    app/controllers/settingsfb_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

any Ideas?

Comment: Show your :set_setting method

Comment: `# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_setting
      @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
    end`
@AlexanderSvetly

Comment: I already tried, initializing `@fbs` at the beginning of the show action in the controller but then my partial renders "Setting" instead of "setting nr 1" (which would be the correct output for `@fbs.name )`

Comment: Then try `@fbs = Setting.find(params[:id])` (at the beginning of the show method)

Comment: this one seems to work! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `@fbs` before rendering after show action. So add `@fbs = Setting.find(params[:id])` at the beginning of the show method.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates there is no @fbs variable. You're calling the settingsFbShow partial from the show.js.erb view but not passing any variables. Try

```
$("#desc").html("<%= j render 'settingsfb/show', locals: {fbs: fbs}  %>");
```

Then in create.js.erb

```
<%= fbs.name %>
```