# Rails 5.2 + Webpacker: rendering a partial inside javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I have a javascript file (something_controller.js.erb; technically Stimulus, but I don't think that matters) where I'd like to include the content of a partial as the HTML it'll append later on.

I [enabled support for ERB with Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb), but a call to `<%= render partial: 'shared/condition' %>` doesn’t work. It simply quietly fails to generate the .js file and include it.

This code doesn’t work:

```
const html = `<%= ApplicationController.renderer.render partial: 'shared/condition' %>`
```

It’s not a renderer.render error, though, because this works:

```
const html = `<%= ApplicationController.renderer.render inline: 'something' %>`
```

The contents of shared/_condition.html.erb isn’t weird, and has no variables:

```
<div data-controller='condition'>
  <a href='#' data-action='condition#remove'><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
  <a href='#' data-toggle="popover" data-target='condition.item' data-action='condition#doNothing'>Item</a>
  <a href='#' data-toggle="popover" data-target='condition.value' data-action='condition#doNothing'>Value</a>
</div>
```

I’ve tried every combination of path I can think of: app/views/shared/condition, /app/views/shared/condition, with the _, with the .html.erb. I've tried rendering `template:` and `file:`... I'm stumped.

Semi-related: is there somewhere I can see any errors generated? The log shows the compilation succeeded in general, but the controller this is in simply isn’t generated. I can’t find any obvious error log.

**ETA: In development.log, this appears:**

```
[Webpacker] Compiling…
  Rendered shared/_condition.html.erb (36.1ms)
[Webpacker] Compiled all packs in /Users/timsullivan/dev/thing/public/packs
```

... so it does seem to be rendering the partial, but the something_controller.js file is not being included in the combined application.js:

[image: something_controller.js is missing!]

In an attempt to find an error somewhere, I tried running:

```
timsullivan$ rails assets:precompile
yarn install v1.6.0
(node:45691) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.49s.
Webpacker is installed  
Using /Users/timsullivan/dev/thing/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
Compiling…
Compiled all packs in /Users/timsullivan/dev/thing/public/packs
```

Comment: Just out of interest, how do you enable `.erb` support in webpacker? I'd love to do that in one of my own projects.

Comment: The [webpacker gem docs](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb) have details, but basically `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb`.

Comment: Instead of loading the html in compiled js, can you not render that partial in a hidden element on the page and use js to access html of that element wherever needed?

Comment: I may ultimately go that way, but I'd like to know where I'm going wrong. Everything seems to be correct, so why isn't it working?

Comment: You could try rendering the file using ERB directly in your javascript file, see here https://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/10/ruby-rendering-erb-template.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're appending the rendered partial to an element with jquery or something, you'll need to escape the contents of the erb tag.

Try this: `"<%= escape_javascript(render("/path/after/views/condition")) %>"`

More thorough explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623813/695186

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't work, unfortunately. I'm using the backtick quotes in ES6, which allow pretty liberal string literals. If I copy the contents of the partial and paste it instead between the backtick quotes, it works fine. I did test your suggestion anyway, just now, to make sure, and the problem remains.